# How to find client information in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a service wrapper that multiple clients from different servers are calling, every server has multiple users, and in our wrapper we want to have information from our client request such as user domain name and IP address, I know that the IP address could be find through `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` but what about user logged on that client server?

For example, say "a.jakson" called wrapper from server "10.100.111.11", how we can find in our wrapper server that this request made by "a.jakson"?

Wrapper is a simple API that is called by other clients and both of them are in the `same domain`.

In point of `authentication`,I'm using **basic authentication** through `authorization header`.

Comment: You need to be much more specific about what service technology and protocol you are using.

Comment: what on earth i got down vote?!  asp.net and a simple api...just that!

Comment: The question is valid: which .Net API do you have? Framework? Core? Which version number?

Comment: asp.net mvc  net framework 4.5

Comment: Do you have Windows authentication configured?

Comment: I'm using local iis and its set on anonymous authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mason for his helpful comment,I decided to use Windows Authentication,the way that give me what i wanted,just set authentication method in webconfig as follows:

```
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
    
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="ax\Domain Users" />
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

it could be also configured by iis maneger as well:

[image]

Now we have access to Client user name in this way:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

consider that client should be passing their credential while calling `wrapper api`

```
     HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be for your client(s) to send these additional details via request headers. I'm not sure what the client is written in so I'll assume you have that taken care of (if not, please open a new question).

Let's say you change the client so that it passes header "username" with value "a.jakson". In the API you could have something as simple as:

```cs
var clientUsername = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["username"];

if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(clientUsername))
{
   // do something with username
}
```

If you want to do this for every request the API receives, you should look into writing the above into a custom middleware.

Comment: of course it's a way,but it's not reasonable to force client send their user name , i was looking for another way...

Comment: I don't mean this to sound rude, but how could you possibly expect to get client details if the client doesn't send them? Assuming the wrapper is running on it's own machine, all it has to go off of is the HTTP request, and its headers are normally where client details like username might be passed. If you have no control over what the client is sending then you don't have any options that I can think of.

Comment: they  are in the same domain...it's only thing that both servers have in common

Comment: Okay - but that doesn't mean that the API has any other information about the client other than what is in the request itself. You're going to have a lot of difficult extracting information that does not exist...

Comment: i think kind of certificate could do the trick or something like this,something before application layer,i mean every client should have installed this certificate or something that send our desire information through the request .

Comment: i mean anything except forcing them to manipulate their codes.